# Apache2 Configuration 404 Error

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, httpd.conf

Our system admin guy has just left a project that I’m working on and I’ve been scrambling trying to configure our Production server to match TEST (where everything works). I’m not very knowledgeable when it comes to server configuration and I’ve been down a lot of dead ends, so I’d very much appreciate any help that can be offered.

I’ve promoted the code from TEST to PROD by copying TEST/var/www to PROD. As a result, the application in PROD now resides in PROD/var/www/www.
I can now access the landing page of the application on Production (my.production.com/www), but I can’t access any files in the subdirectories of var/www/www/. I keep getting a 404 Not Found error.

I’ve copied the configuration for the site (the file called ‘realto’) from TEST to PROD and have run a2ensite to create the symlinks to the sites-enabled folder, but I still get the 404 error in Production.

Can anyone advise me on what might be the issue, or point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I've included the text of the httpd.conf, ports.conf, and site configuration files below.

httpd.conf:

```
ServerName    my.server.com
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
<Directory />
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<DirectoryMatch /var/www/*>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride All
  Options None
</DirectoryMatch>
<DirectoryMatch phpmyadmin>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  Options None
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Site Configuration File:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xxx@xxxxxxxx.xxx

    DocumentRoot /var/www/www
    <Directory />
        #Options FollowSymLinks
        #AllowOverride None
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
                #RewriteEngine On
                #RewriteBase /
                #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
                #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
                #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
                #RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
                #RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all

        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/www/application/configs/>
          <Files ~ "\.ini$">
                Deny from All
          </Files>
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

ports.conf:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are test and prod on the same machine? From your question it appears that prod is in a subdirectory of test? That doesn't sound right.. Also, could you post your vhosts on a pastebin? You probably won't get many people willing to download files from a third party site without knowing for sure what they contain...

Comment: Thanks @bradym, I've edited the question to include the vhosts. TEST and PROD are independent virtual machines in the cloud; prod is not in a subdirectory of test.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is make the DocumentRoot and  entries match.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/www
<Directory /var/www/www>
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    #RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    #RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all

    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

With this DocumentRoot, accessing your site will serve what's in /var/www/www. Which means that accessing http://example.com/www would actually be looking in /var/www/www/www for files.

Now that the DocumentRoot and Directory directive match, do you really want all of the mod_rewrite rules commented out? As it is now, you'll get a 404 when requesting any file that doesn't physically exist in /var/www/www. If your app requires routing requests to index.php, you'll need to uncomment those lines. (I'm guessing they might be commented out for testing, but just in case...)

As a side note, in the future I'd suggest a less confusing docroot path. Sometimes it can be hard to see repeated words/characters, so it would be easier to identify typos with something less repetitive.

I like to setup my applications like this:

```
/var/www/example.com/test/htdocs
/var/www/example.com/www/htdocs
```

That way, it's immediately clear which environment you're in, and it's not so confusing.

Comment: Thanks @bradym. I've made the suggested changes, including un-commenting the rewrite conditions and restarted the server, but now I get an error when attempting to access anywhere on the site (previously visitors were redirected to our blog site contained in `/var/www/blog` folder, but they can no longer see this content). Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I don't see anything in the above question about the blog folder, so I'm not sure how that redirect was being executed. Where is the index.php file located for your site? Is it in /var/www or /var/www/www? Wherever that index.php file is located is where the DirectoryRoot should point. I was assuming that you'd want the site to render at example.com/ not example.com/www when I suggested the the above changes. Not sure if that's the case or not.